# 1999 Ford F250 XLT Super Duty – Oil in coolant

Tags: engine, cooling

My truck has the 6.8l V10 Triton engine in it. When I got it there was a lot of oil in the cooling system but no water in the oil.  It ran hot once but didn't do it again. Would it be the head gasket and how should I clean the cooling system out to get all the oil out of it?

Comment: This is a diesal, correct?  Is your primary objective to simply drain the cooling system or do you want to know about howto replace the head gasket?

Comment: No its not a diesel its gas and yes how do I change the head gasket I'm not sure if its blown or if the head or block is cracked I did a compression test on it and they all seem to be the same there like 150 on each of them so I don't even know if its the head at all?

Comment: Yeah I would assume that would be it I also saw that if it has a oil cooler built in the radiator if it got leak then oil  could get in that way to and water still not get in the oil so I just don't know?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?